# Dash collecting our data

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to create data visualization about my company data and willing to use Dash from Plotly. I use the csv file and then load it as Dataframe. When I try running it with dash in offline mode, the chart is not showing. But when I try running it with online mode, the chart is shown. I try to check it from terminal and there's connection and transaction data from my PC to an IP address that's known as Fastly if I'm not mistaken. Do they take my data that I used in Dash to their side?

Thank you

Comment: The `dash` tag is about the dash shell.  You seem to be referring to something else.  A different tag would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Dash worked on your side as local server. If you want to show other people your dashboard, I recommend you to try something like Heroku. [Here](https://dash.plot.ly/deployment) is example how to run your python script on Heroku or Flask server and make it available to anyone from the Internet